# How to change different topics pace in rosbag?

Tags: ros, rosbag, topic, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have 2 topics (A and B) in rosbag. but they are not synchrinized, A is 10s ahead of B. So I want to create a new rosbag and make A 10s delay to synchronize with B.

How should I do that ?

should I change the header.stamp to make it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262181/how-to-change-different-topics-pace-in-rosbag?/) by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2017-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the [rosbag API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API) to recreate your bag file with new stamps.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0